# how make if condition work with data type BOOLEAN

Tags: android

I am a new application developer ..I trying to do a system to block users in my app
I created a field in the database called blok Type how make if condition work with data type BOOLEAN it has two value ​​zero or one.
So if user has block number of field will be 1 and if he is normal will be 0.

I fetch user data by Volley..So I try to make if condition in Volley but it doesn't work.

I try like that :

```
 if (blok.equals(0)) {


Toast.makeText(ProfileUsers.this, "You are block ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}else {
Toast.makeText(ProfileUsers.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

And like that :

```
if (blok.length() > 0) {
      Toast.makeText(Users.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
 } else {
      Toast.makeText(Users.this, "You are block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
}
```

Volley Code

```
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                            if (success.equals("1")){

                                for (int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String blok = object.getString("blok").trim();
                                    Log.i(TAG, "test"+blok.toString());
                               }
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String > params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Id", Id);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

So I don't  know if my idea is correct, or is there a different, better way to make block for user.

if anyone know how can makes my code work help me please

Comment: what is the type of blok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are comparing a `string` with an `int` which is wrong, try this instead:**

```
if (blok.equals("0")) {

    Toast.makeText(ProfileUsers.this, "You are block ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} else {

 Toast.makeText(ProfileUsers.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```